# How to count unique combinations from a data table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, combinations

I have a data table with three columns. The first two are a collection of the data points (categorical data that can be either A, B, or C). The third column is a concatenation of the two data points as they belong to a set. I need to get the counts of the possible combinations and need to count "A & C" as part of the same group as "C & A" since the order of these pairs doesn't matter.

Previously, I set up a column that concatenated "CAT1 & CAT2" and then another as "CAT2 & CAT1" hoping to sum up there, but those numbers of course don't add up properly then.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(CAT1 = c('a','b','c','b','a','c','c','b','a','c'),
                 CAT2 = c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a'))

dt1[,merged := paste(dt1$CAT1, dt1$CAT2, sep = ' & ')]

counts = data.table(table(dt1$merged))
```

The output table "counts" gives me all the uniques of the merged column, but I need to sum up anywhere the data points are flipped ("A & C" + "C & A"). I recognize that this could be done manually, but I have far too many actual data points to do by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt1[,paste(sort(c(CAT1,CAT2)),collapse=" & "),by=1:nrow(dt1)][,table(V1)]
```

Comment: another possibility: `dt1[, table(paste(pmin(CAT1, CAT2), pmax(CAT1, CAT2), sep=' & '))]`

Comment: Could be obvious to some, but in order for this answer to work the class has to be characters. Tried it with factors unknowingly and failed miserably until set to characters. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this- 
Note- As mentioned by @chinsoon12, we can use `pmin` & `pmax`

```
 > setDT(dt1)[,list(Count=.N) ,paste(pmin(CAT1, CAT2), pmax(CAT1, CAT2), sep=' & ')]
   paste Count
1: a & a     1
2: b & b     2
3: c & c     2
4: a & b     2
5: a & c     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no good with data.table, so here's my answer with a data.frame:

Just sort the two CATs before pasting, making sure they're always in the same order.

```
 dt1$merged<-apply(dt1,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse=" & "))
```

I'm sure there's a faster way to do in with data.table, but I'm not sure how. A naive `sort` added to your code came up with an error...